# php sql importing ID and Text to testarea then posting both values after changes were made to the Text

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, textarea

So I have a file called Names.html.php that displays the data from the table in my sql table easily. It has an edit and delete button. The edit button allows users to edit the text in the "notes" column of the table which is longtext value (but did start as text).

The edit button sends the ID of the record that was chosen to the EditNote.php where it then opens that record using the function in databasefunctions.php and displays it using the EditNote.html.php.

My issue comes when I change the text in the Textarea box and click Save no errors appear but the text is not updated in the table. I know the ID value is being passed correctly but I am wondering whether there could be an issue with the Textarea posting not refreshing? Or having 2 post values from the same form causing some issues? Either way I am not sure how to fix either issue so some help would be greatly appreciated :)

Names.html.php

```
<blockquote>
  <p>

  <?=htmlspecialchars($Names['Name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?>
  <?=htmlspecialchars($Names['Notes'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?>
  <?=htmlspecialchars($Names['Punch_IN_Time'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?>
  <?=htmlspecialchars($Names['Status'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?>

  <a href="EditNote.php?idss=<?=$Names['Punch_ID']?>">Edit</a>

  <form action="DeleteEntry.php" method = "post">
    <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="<?=$Names['Punch_ID']?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
  </form>
  </p>
</blockquote>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

EditNote.php

```
<?php
include '_DIR_' . '/../../Include/DatabaseConnection.php';
include '_DIR_' . '/../../Include/DatabaseFunctions.php';

try {
  if (isset($_POST['NotePage'])) {
    $note = (string)$_POST['NotePage'];
    $IDs = (int)$_POST['Pid'];

    UpdateNotes($pdo, $IDs, $note);

  header('location: Punchinoutlist.php');
  }else{
    $Note = getPunchLine($pdo, $_GET['idss']);

    $title = 'Edit Note';

    ob_start();

    include '_DIR_' . '/../../Templates/EditNote.html.php';

    $output = ob_get_clean();
  }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  $title = 'An error has occurred';

  $output = 'Database error: ' . $e->getMessage() . ' in ' .$e->getFile() . ':' . $e->getLine();
}

include '_DIR_' . '/../../Templates/Layout.html.php';

 ?>
```

EditNote.html.php

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name"Pid" value="<?=$Note['Punch_ID'];?>">
  <label for = "NotePage">Type your new note here:
  </label>
  <textarea id = "NotePage" name="NotePage"
    rows="3" cols ="40"><?=$Note['Notes']?>
  </textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

DatabaseFunctions.php

```
// Main query function that all fucntions refer //

function query($pdo, $sql, $parameters = []){
  $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute($parameters);
  return $query;
 }

//update function for updating the note column of a certain record in the punch_in_out table //

function UpdateNotes($pdo, $id, $Notes){
  $parameters = [':Notes' => $Notes, ':id' => $id];

  $query = 'UPDATE `punch_in_out` SET `Notes` = :Notes WHERE `Punch_ID` = :id';

  query($pdo, $query, $parameters);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're getting your ID when you `POST` the text update because you're missing an `=` after the `name` in your HTML.

```
// you have
 <input type="hidden" name"Pid" value="<?=$Note['Punch_ID'];?>">

// you should have
 <input type="hidden" name="Pid" value="<?=$Note['Punch_ID'];?>">
```

Comment: damn >< always something so small . . . Thank you very much